# mongo lite server connexion with proxy with R

Tags: r, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongolite

I am looking to connect to a server using the mongolite package of R but I have the following error

Error: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection timeout calling ismaster on 'XXX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX'] where XX are the IP of the server.

Additionaly I have tried to use a proxy to reach out the required server without success.
I have try to create a .Renvion file in my user/Home
and adding the folowing line into this conf file

options(internet.info = 0) 
http_proxy=//proxy.serv:0000/ where 0000 are the port of the proxy

Then I am calling the require serveur with its URL in the command line below
mongo(url = "mongodb://XXX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX", db = "TEST",collection = "TEST1")

without success.

I have allowed the firewall security to the required serveur going forward.

Any Help?

Comment: Can you connect to the database via shell? `telnet  XXX.XX.XX.XXX XXXX` ?

Comment: no I have tried shell("telnet XXX.XX.XX.XXX:XXXX") without success is that the right command, I am using Rstudio 3.4 and I do not have the Tools --> Options to add the terminal

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet. Run it from the console to confirm the DB is up and running, listens on the expected interface and port, and no firewall blocks tcp traffic. If transport layer works, try to connect to the database with mongo shell https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/client/ It will confirm username and password are correct, and user has access to collection TEST1 on the TEST database. It will let to localise the problem. With current edition the question is way too broad.

Comment: in fact this is the mongolite package that I am using and I really do not know how to set the proxy connection

Comment: Well, repeating that you have a problem won't help to solve it. I am asking you to prove the mongodb is running and accessible to start from. It is impossible to connect to a turned off database, so please confirm it is running and properly configured by using telnet and/or mongo shell. Regarding the proxy - I doubt an http one can help anyway. Mongo doesn't speak http.

Comment: I am trying to reach the terminal so I can exec the shell witouth success I had a look in the Tools but it is not visible, neither in Tools --> Options the pane is not there... I have at last tried to open it with a shortcut SHIFT + ALT + T it is not working... Do you think it is link to the version of Rstudio? I am using the 3.4

Comment: terminal/console/command prompt - is a standalone system utility. It has nothing to do with Rstudio.